# UE4 C++ - Adding an object with a `TArray` member by value to a `TArray` causes a segfault

Tags: arrays, c++11, unreal-engine4

I have some code that creates a vector of strings in one function, converts that to a `TArray<FString>`, assigns it to the member variable of an object, and adds that object to a `TArray`, something like below:

```
void MyMethod() {
   std::vector<std::string> vec = GetVec();
   TArray<FString> arr = VecStrToTArrFStr(vec);

   MyObject obj;
   obj.value = arr;

   this->Objects.Add(obj);
}
```

Where the function `VecStrToTArrFStr` is as follows:

```
inline TArray<FString> VecStrToTArrFStr(std::vector<std::string> &vec) {
  TArray<FString> arr;
  arr.SetNumUninitialized(vec.size());

  for (auto &item : vec) {
    arr.Add(FString(UTF8_TO_TCHAR(item.c_str())));
  }

  return arr;
}
```

This issue occurs on this line:

```
this->Objects.Add(obj);
```

For some reason, copying the array throws a segfault. Specifically, it gives this call stack:

- `__memcpy_avx_unaligned (@7fffec5b4ea0..7fffec5b5226:173)`
- `FGenericPlatformMemory::Memcpy(void*, void const*, unsigned long) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/GenericPlatform/GenericPlatformMemory.h:348)`
- `FMemory::Memcpy(void*, void const*, unsigned long) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/UnrealMemory.h:124)`
- `TEnableIf<TIsBitwiseConstructible<wchar_t, wchar_t>::Value, void>::Type ConstructItems<wchar_t, wchar_t>(void*, wchar_t const*, int) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/MemoryOps.h:137)`
- `void TArray<wchar_t, FDefaultAllocator>::CopyToEmpty<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, int, int, int) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Array.h:2508)`
- `TArray<wchar_t, FDefaultAllocator>::TArray(TArray<wchar_t, FDefaultAllocator> const&) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Array.h:338)`
- `FString::FString(FString const&) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/UnrealString.h:73)`
- `TEnableIf<!(TIsBitwiseConstructible<FString, FString>::Value), void>::Type ConstructItems<FString, FString>(void*, FString const*, int) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/MemoryOps.h:126)`
- `void TArray<FString, FDefaultAllocator>::CopyToEmpty<FString>(FString const*, int, int, int) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Array.h:2508)`
- `TArray<FString, FDefaultAllocator>::TArray(TArray<FString, FDefaultAllocator> const&) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Array.h:338)`
- `MyObject::MyObject(MyObject const&) (MyObject.h)`
- `int TArray<MyObject, FDefaultAllocator>::Emplace<MyObject const&>(MyObject const&&&) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Array.h:1843)`
- `TArray<MyObject, FDefaultAllocator>::Add(MyObject const&) (/UnrealEngine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/Array.h:1916)`

Everything runs perfectly fine if I change `MyObject.value` to be of type `std::vector<std::string>` and just assign it the `vec`, but attempting to assign it a `TArray<FString>` throws a segfault.

What could be causing this? Does it have something to do with how I'm creating my `FString` objects, or how I'm creating my `TArray`? Is UE4 doing some garbage collection on the `TArray` in `VecStrToArrFStr` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've populated the array with garbage `FString` objects; when you call `TArray::Add`, the `FString` copy constructor attempts to perform a bitwise copy on its members resulting in dereferencing a garbage pointer, causing a sigsegv.

To resolve, remove the call to `SetNumUninitialized`; it doesn't do what you think it does. This call doesn't just reserve the space, you're actually adding the specified number of garbage (uninitialised) `FStrings` into the array, then putting the "real" ones on the end of them. Have a look at what state your array ends up in after the call to `VecStrToTArrFStr`.

https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/SetNumUninitialized/index.html

Comment: Ahh that's it. Thanks!